# My console project won't proceed to the next, being stuck in an using sentence

Tags: c#, oracle11g

**THIS IS MY CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Insert
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start....");

            String connString = "User Id=******;Password=*********;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=***.**.**.***)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=****))); Connection Timeout=5";

            Console.WriteLine("connString was created....");

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("start using sentence....");

                using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connString))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("in using scope....before connection opens....");

                    connection.Open();

                    OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

                    Console.WriteLine(connection.ServerVersion);

                    Console.WriteLine("Myworld");    

                    cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO PROCESS_TEST ( TEST ) VALUES ( {0} )", "1");

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TEST FROM PROCESS_TEST";
                    OracleDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (read.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(read.GetString(0));
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                Console.Read();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

**IT WORKS** *If I run the code on my visual studio 2013.*

**IT DOES NOT WORK** *when I run the exe in its **Release** folder.*

I inserted the try-catch code later to find out about what's going on but it doesn't throw any error as well, no matter how long I wait for my exe to give an error. It's weird, considering the connetion timeout is set to 5 sec...

[image]

It doesn't go any further than this step. Running the exe with administrator authority doesn't work either.

Let me tell you again, **it works very very well on my visual studio 2013**

What's the problem with it?

---

**UPDATED**

It turns out that my code **works okay either with .exe after all**, *except that it randomly takes 3~10 minutes to finish the job*, which is not what I want as well.

Why does it take so long to open the connection? Could the connection work take so long like 4~10 minutes when an app is running under standalone process like exe?

It's a running database server for my web application and the connection job has never bothered me before.

My exe does the rest of its job ( the insert work ) blazing fast, as long as the connection is opened.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in your Oracle database connection. `using` doesn't actually do anything when its "run".

Comment: @Aron yeah it does look like so. I updated my question and it turns out that it works anyway. But it takes too long to open the connection. I completely don't get it. My oracle server works greatly and it is currently doing its job very well with my web application.